# Targetting heals

Tags: neverwinter

As a cleric, there is a single-target heal spell.  I have been able to use it by pointing my mouse over my teammate and pressing the bound key.  Is there a way to target this heal other than by pointing at a  teammate?  I ask this because sometimes there are a lot of teammates standing next to each other and it becomes hard to target one specific teammate.

Answer (score 6):

If you target someone and hold ctrl, your camera ***and targeting*** will follow them ***until you release ctrl***. Then if you cast a targeted ability, I believe it will hit them.

I just tested this in town with Healing Word, and it seemed to work fine. Hoping that translates to dungeons.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't any other way yet. I still hope that they will introduce a change to this, but i guess they made so healing is much more difficult than it used to be in other games.

Comment: It's just like targeting mobs, then. That's the bit of the game that is nice for an FPS player, but annoyed for a turn-based player. Action!-RPG.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can lock to a target by pressing down the left control (LCtrl) key.  That's a bit cumbersome while in a large battle.  Instead, you can reprogram the game to have the control key, or any other key you find convenient, toggle between locked and unlocked (press/release the key once to lock, press/release a second time to unlock)

```
/bind <key> "++HardTargetLock"
```

You insert the key you want instead of `<key>`.

Personally I used a key I don't normally use during game play, and then programmed a button on my game mouse to press that key.  That lets me target / untarget someone by pressing that mouse button.